# Why is not a global variable recognized in a function

Tags: php

Why is an empty line printed instead of 5?

```
function test()
{   
 echo "$a <br/>";   
}

$a = 5;
test();
```

Comment: *(related)* [Global in Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/global-in-functions/5166527#5166527)

Comment: Are you sure `<br/>` isn't outputted?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: [It should error](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FZwQbz), maybe error reporting is off.

Comment: @alex - http://codepad.org/1FIE7Tsu

Comment: @JaredFarrish: http://codepad.org/tBVUIeS6 -> The error and the `<br />`. I suppose I should have said it should *issue a notice*.

Comment: @alex - *I* understand what you mean, but what I meant was that `<br/>` in the HTML source would be an indication of the overall problem, regardless of any (non-existent) error reporting.

Answer (score 6):

Functions in PHP do not inherit global scope or parent scope (unless using an anonymous function with `use()`).

You can use the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword to access them.

```
function test()
{
 global $a;   
 echo "$a <br/>";   
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/SK3zBC).

---

[Jared Farish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451969/jared-farrish) also points out the use of the global associative array [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) which holds all global variables and which, like any super global such as `$_POST`, `$_GET`, etc, is in scope everywhere.

```
function test()
{   
 echo "$GLOBALS[a] <br/>";   
}

$a = 5;
test();
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oBdHjT).

---

You could use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)...

```
$a = 5;

$test = function() use ($a) {
    echo $a;
};

$test();
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AdlmHG).

---

As a footnote, [try not to rely on global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why). They *can* be a sign of poor program design if you overly rely on them.

Comment: I know, I know, but OP: *Please refrain from unnecessary `global` variables*.

Comment: Also, `$GLOBALS['a'] = 5;` could be used with `global $a;`. Though I will admit I haven't mastered the difference.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Oh yeah, though I've never used `$GLOBALS`. Made an edit :)

Comment: IMHO, even using 'use()' will not give you access to global scope you can only access the value of variables _at the time they are passed_, unless passed by reference.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I sacrificed the love of '$GLOBALS' for beauty of stable code.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to use the `global`

```
function test()
{   
  global $a;
  echo "$a <br/>";   
}

$a = 5;
test();
```

Comment: use parameters instead `test($a)`

Comment: It's a little *rich* to say "don't do this" when the upvoted answer *demonstrates this exactly*.